# Web based Python package download tool

Tags: python, pip, package, lib

I have a PC that is offline, that has Python 3.4.3 on it.

The only way I have access to the internet is via a small Android tablet, which does not have Python installed. Which means I cannot use `pip` to download packages.

I want to be able to download Python packages (for example *pandas*), along with all the necessary dependencies, for my particular Python version and platform, using only a web browser (Chrome in my case) on my tablet.
I want to be able to download all the files that this command would, but without the `pip`:

```
pip install --download C:\py_cache\ pandas
```

Later, I would copy the files from the tablet to the PC, and use pip on the PC to install from the local copies. For example:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links C:\py_cache\ pandas
```

Is there a web based tool that would allow me to download all the necessary files?

Comment: No, you have to do this with `pip`. Do that on an internet-connected PC. Or route network via your tablet to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the .whl (wheel) file of the dependency with your tablet.
Transfer the file to you computer and install it via

```
pip install package-name.whl
```

But you have to have pip installed already.
You can also thether the internet to the PC over USB.

Comment: It's not enough to download just one wheel. The OP needs to download all dependencies and it's quite tedious to do without `pip` because dependencies have their own dependencies recursively.